# Ruby request to Google timezone API returns ECONNRESET but works from browser

Tags: ruby, json, https, google-api

My RoR web application needs to send a request to Google timezone API so I added the following Ruby code to the controller:

```
300:    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?sensor=false&location=34.0617109,-118.4017053&timestamp=16071"
301:    uri = URI.parse(url)
302:    raw_response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
303:    parsed_response = JSON(raw_response)
```

but it fails, and I see the following log on the server

```
Errno::ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer):
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:302:in `get_rate'

Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.9ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (5.2ms)
```

If I copy the above url and paste it to my browser (Safari), all works fine and I get the following expected response

```
{
   "dstOffset" : 0,
   "rawOffset" : -28800,
   "status" : "OK",
   "timeZoneId" : "America/Los_Angeles",
   "timeZoneName" : "Pacific Standard Time"
}
```

The same web app sends the following request to Google geocode API and all works perfectly:

```
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=90212&sensor=false"
uri = URI.parse(url)
raw_response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
parsed_response = JSON(raw_response)
```

Anyone can please point me to what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to my own question for others to learn form.

After a lot of research and tries, here is the solution that worked for me:

1 - I needed a key to use Google Timezone API. The requests work fine when you use a browser, but in order to use the API, you need a key and you can get it for free from [here](https://console.developers.google.com)

2 - this is how I changed my Ruby code to get it to work

```
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?sensor=false&location=34.0617109,-118.4017053&timestamp=16071&key=<google_timezone_api_key_here>"
uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
raw_response = http.request request
parsed_response = JSON(raw_response)
```

The strange thing for me is that, unlike for http requests, the https response I was looking for (the one that's returned if I send the request from the browser) is in raw_response.body and not in parsed_response.
I hope someone else can explain why?